# When to use "of" preposition

Tags: prepositions

I am often bump in the "of" preposition in different sentences. Here are some of these:

> The new professor is **of** Turkish descent.
>
> He is a citizen **of** Russia.
>
> I dream **of** visiting Europe.

Here are examples when you wish to use the "of" preposition but need to use another one:

> The new computer **from** the tech giant.
>
> The Nile is the longest river **in** the world.
>
> The girl recovered **from** her illness.

What the global rule one can follow to not make mistakes in speech construction?

Comment: There are no global rules (or, more accurately, the global rules that exist are partial and inconsistently applied). The use of prepositions (or equivalent) is one of the most idiosyncratic parts of a language - certainly of English, and of all other languages I am at all familiar with.

Comment: That is like saying when do I use the genitive in Russian?

Answer (score 2):

A good dictionary is a great help. Make sure to consult it when you have doubts.

As for your examples, it's possible to say not only "**of** Turkish descent" but also "Turkish **by** descent".

You can dream **of** or **about** visiting Europe, and you can actually say "river **of** the world"(http://www.primaryhomeworkhelp.co.uk/rivers/longest.htm).

You can only recover **from** something and be a citizen **of** some country (*of* shows the relationship of belonging between one thing and another (a citizen and a country)).

In the phrase "the new computer from the tech giant", **from** shows the *origin* of the computer (we use *from* for the same reason saying *furniture from Spain* or *I am from Canada*).

All in all, sometimes it's possible to find a logical explanation for the use of certain prepositions, but sometimes we'd better just remember something as a prepositional phrase.

Comment: Mostly I agree with your answer, but "the new computer **of** the tech giant", and "furniture **of** Spain" cannot be entirely ruled out. Nor equally, can the alternative genitive "The tech giant's new computer" and "Spain's furniture".